# Docker Openshift Security unidirectional route

Tags: docker, openshift

When I deploy a docker image to Openshift V3, is it possible to add a route that is unidirectional?

i.e. can I make a route that only allows requests to my docker image, and does not allow the docker image to initiate a request.

The idea is that I want to be able to guarantee that a possibly malicious docker image can not call out to other mircoservices in the aPaaS environment.

Comment: If your OpenShift environment is setup for multitenancy using  ovs-multitenant (the default), then run that application in a project of its own.

Comment: thanks, makes perfect  sense.